# How to use BlurAdmin template with Laravel 5.3

Tags: view, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel (or any PHP Framework) for the first time and want to use [BlurAdmin](https://akveo.github.io/blur-admin/) template for my web app. I've never worked on AngularJS and as per my understanding Blur is built using that. I'm not able to figure out even where/how to start using this template with Laravel.

So far, I have followed the installation procedure as per the [guidelines](https://akveo.github.io/blur-admin/articles/002-installation-guidelines/) and cloned the GitHub repository into my Laravel Project's Folder.

PS: I'm aware that this is not how I'm supposed to post a question on SO, but I'm not able to find any resource online. Please help me out.

Comment: are u able to run blur-admin on localhost?

Comment: No, I finally settled for AdminLTE Template

Comment: I have configured it with laravel 5.0. I am posting the answer below (in a while ) , plz do accept it, so it can be useful for others. Thanks

Comment: @Saad: Sure. Will do

Comment: to run blur-admin on localhost, install NPM, install bower, run npm install, gulp, and it will create a release directory where the htmls will be working just like the demo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to run blur admin with laravel 5.0  (Blade template)

Download blur admin from
https://akveo.github.io/blur-admin/articles/091-downloads/
( Links for downloads )

Go to the "dev-release" folder and run index.html. So we will now have concern with "dev-release" folder.

-------- Integration with laravel 5.0------

1- Create the folder with any name (admin) in "/public" of laravel
2- Copy the folders (app,assets,fonts and lib) from "dev-release" to /public/admin
3- Create the folder with any name (back) in "/app/resources/views/" of laravel
4- Copy the files 'auth.html' and 'index.html' from "dev-release" to 'resources/views/back' and rename them to 'auth.blade.php' and 'index.blade.php'
5- In 'index.blade.php' and 'auth.blade.php' set all the links of img, styles and js in according to blade template like

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{{asset('admin/assets/img/favicon-16x16.png')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('admin/lib/ionicons.css')}}" >
<script src="{{asset('admin/lib/jquery.js')}}"></script>
```

6- It is not over yet. Create the javascript variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var adminPath="{{asset('admin')}}"; 
   </script>
```

in index.blade.php above the place which includes all javascripts.
7- Search through all the js files of "public/admin/app/pages" and add this variable before the url that contain "app/pages..."
You may need to change the url in html files also
8- Lastly create the route  in 'app/Http/routes.php'

```
Route::get('Admin-Login',function(){
    return view('back.auth');
});

Route::get('Dashboard',function(){
    return view('back.index');
});
```

It will create the running copy with urls
projName/Admin-Login
and
projName/Dashboard